# React Native formatting issues with prettier

Tags: reactjs, react-native, prettier

I am using the default formatting settings for React Native project. Prettier ("@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",). My if statements do not look good at least to me. I like to know if my if statements should be formatted as shown below or differently. Below is how prettier is formatting. Is there a better method. If so please post detailed information

```
const connect = async (addresses, port) => {
  // check purchase information (entitlement)
  try {
    const purchaserInfo = await Purchases.getPurchaserInfo();
    if (
      typeof purchaserInfo.entitlements.active[DEFAULT_ENTITLEMENT_ID] !==
      "undefined"
    ) {
      // Grant user "pro" access
      setNetwork(`http://${addresses[0]}:${port}`);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Error fetching purchaser info
    Bugfender.d('Purchases Error', e.message ); //prettier-ignore
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your if condition is lengthy.
By default, Prettier’s printing algorithm prints expressions on a **single line** if they fit. It really helps **readability** if **long single line** converted to **multi line**. That's why long single line are **automatically expanded**.

[Click here to read more](https://prettier.io/docs/en/rationale.html)